# Add checkbox to select rows that displayed by displayTag

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jsp, checkbox, struts2

I'm new in struts2 and displayTag.
I have a jsp page that fetch a table from database and display it in the jsp page.
I want to add checkbox to the rows to select and send back them to the database.
I actually using hibernate for fetching and restoring data in database...

what can I do to add checkbox and some rows?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What exact problem do you have?

Comment: I need to know what king of tag properties should I use to add checkbox for every row?!

Comment: You can add checkbox using simple struts2 or html code in every display tag row.

Answer (score 0):

For checkbox, this is the code `<input type="checkbox" name="toselect" value="Y" />`
can you please post your JSP page which actually displays the fetched data from JSP?

Answer (score 0):

this a jsp page that try to add checkBox beside every row to select some of them and post back the selected rows to action

```
<s:form action="FetchData" name="userInformation">
    <display:table name="usersList" id="username" form="userInformation">
        <display:column property="username" title="نام کاربری" paramProperty="checkbox"/>
        <display:column property="portfolioName" title="نام حساب کاربری سیستم" paramProperty="checkbox"></display:column>
        <display:column property="firstName" title="نام"></display:column>
        <display:column property="lastName"/>
        <display:column property="fatherName"/>
        <display:column property="sex"/>
        <display:column property="nationalId"/>
        <display:column property="phoneNumber"/>
    </display:table>

</s:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this..
structure your columns like this,onsubmit all checked checkbox values will be posted based on name to action

<display:column title="Folder"  headerClass="text" class="text" style="width:10%" sortable="true">
<input type="checkbox" name="toselect" value="${row.folderName}" /><c:out value="${row.folderName}"/>
                </display:column>
```